# Change rendered components depending on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a very simple website where I have an image, a couple h1/2 elements and two buttons.

My goal is that when I click the login button, the buttons dissapear and a box containing a login form appears.

The same for the register button but with the register box.

I'm rendering the buttons, or one of the 2 boxes depending on the state but so far my code doesn't seem to be working.

Whenever I click a button nothing happens, it should re-render if I'm not wrong but it's not happening.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../logo.png';
import './css/AddGame.scss';
import AddGameButton from './AddGameButton';

class AddGame extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pageState: "buttons",
    }
  }

  openLogin() {
    this.setState({
      pageState: "login",
    });
  }

  openRegister() {
    this.setState({
      pageState: "register",
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="AddGame">
        <img src={logo} />
        <h1><span>OPlist</span> estará disponible próximamente.</h1>
        <h2>¿Quieres contribuir añadiendo juegos?</h2>
        {(this.state.pageState == "buttons") ? <div>
          <AddGameButton onclick={this.openLogin} text="Entrar" buttonType="Login" /> <AddGameButton onclick={this.openRegister} text="Regístrate" buttonType="Register" />
        </div> : null}
        {(this.state.pageState == "login") ? <div>LOGIN</div> : null}
        {(this.state.pageState == "register") ? <div>register</div> : null}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddGame;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your handlers are called from the `AddGameButton` component and they will have a different `this` when run in that context.

(*read https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html*)

Either define them as arrow functions or bind `this` to them in the constructor.

Arrow function way

```
  openLogin = () => {
    this.setState({
      pageState: "login",
    });
  }

  openRegister = () => {
    this.setState({
      pageState: "register",
    });
  }
```

Bind `this` in the `constructor` way

```
constructor () {
  super();
  this.state = {
    pageState: "buttons",
  }
  this.openLogin = this.openLogin.bind(this)
  this.openRegister = this.openRegister.bind(this)
}
```

Demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/x7x1848yp

Comment: Wow thanks! I am pretty new to JS and React (I come from Java and I'm a beginner at coding in general) and I struggle with the `this` statement and arrow functions a lot. How would you bind the methods in the constructor?